# Publications in personal statement

Tags: publications, statement-of-purpose

What is the best way to include publications in my statement-of-purpose which I want to submit to a university? Should I give a full description of my publications, or just list them?

Comment: Put them in your CV.

Answer (score 1):

This would depend a bit on whether the publications are relevant for your request. I would suggest a two-fold approach:

- A list of all publications in your CV, in usual bibliographical style.
- A list of relevant publications, with a short comment on each, the affiliation under which it was published, and the connection it has to the studies you now wish to undertake, within the statement of purpose.

This will help the people making the decision understand you have a focus on what you are doing. You are not only telling them what you want to do, but also how you came to want it.

Best luck!

Comment: +1: I'd emphasize again: "relevant publications". Be very selective and try not to repeat too much with your research goal. Mention 1-2 unique aspects about paper that resonate with or reinforce your goals and aspirations. For instance, if your goal is to do more community-based research, and in one paper you invited a community stakeholder to be a co-author, then you can highlight that as a point that made you particularly proud about that publication in the statement.